# How singleton works in Dart?

Tags: dart, singleton

I am new to Dart and Flutter. While I am going through tutorials, I got that we can make singleton using factory keyword. But after that, I got this code.

```
class AccountService {
  static final _instance = AccountService._internal();

  AccountService._internal();

  static AccountService getInstance() {
    return _instance;
  }
}
```

My questions.

1. How does the code work?
2. when `getInstance()` get called?
3. is `AccountService._internal()` a constructor?
4. `static final _instance = AccountService._internal();` - When this get called?

Please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Static fields in Dart are all lazy evaluated so they will first get its value the first time you access the field.

So:

1. When you call `getInstance()`, it will return the value of the field `_instance`. If this is the first time the field will be evaluated so `AccountService._internal()` is called. If it is second time, the value from previous access is reused.
2. First time you call the method somewhere in your code? If you are never calling the method, the object referenced by `_instance` will never be created.
3. Yes, it is a named constructor and because the name starts with "_" it is only available from the library this class is part of. By doing so, it is possible to restrict new objects from this class so only the class itself are allowed to create an instance.
4. It is called first time `_instance` is accessed. Since this name also starts with "_" it is only available from the library this class is part of.

The lazy initialization of static fields is described in the Dart specification with the following reasoning:

> Static variable declarations with an initializing expression are initializedlazily (8.1).
>
> *The lazy semantics are given because we do not want a language where one tends to define expensive initialization computations, causing long application startup times. This is especially crucial for Dart, which must support the coding of client applications.*

https://dart.dev/guides/language/specifications/DartLangSpec-v2.2.pdf

**Added code example**

```
class AccountService {
  static final _instance = AccountService._internal();

  AccountService._internal() {
    print(':: Calling AccountService._internal constructor');
  }

  static AccountService getInstance() {
    print(':: Calling getInstance()');
    return _instance;
  }
}

void main() {
  print(':: Step 1');
  AccountService.getInstance();
  print(':: Step 2');
  AccountService.getInstance();
  print(':: End');
}
```

Output:

```
:: Start
:: Step 1
:: Calling getInstance()
:: Calling AccountService._internal constructor
:: Step 2
:: Calling getInstance()
:: End
```

Comment: [Effective dart reference](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#libraries) to making members private using `_`.

Comment: For the first time, which gets called this one static final _instance = AccountService._internal(); or

  AccountService._internal(); ?

Comment: The call flow will be: `getInstance()` -> `static final _instance = AccountService._internal()` -> `AccountService._internal()`. The constructor must always be called to create the instance of the class. You can try add a print statement inside the constructor to see it is called only once.